# VRP with different vehicle types using or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to optimize the best routes VRP with OR-Tools. I couldn't find the right function in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/constraint_solver/routing/RoutingModel).

***CASE***: Some customers only accept pickup trucks, some accept only trucks, some accept both trucks, pickup, and vans. There's a single depot location and vehicles should carry orders to the right customers with accepted vehicles.

Those vehicles I have

[image]

Customers accept those vehicle types

[image]

These vehicles should be directed to the appropriate customers.

Do you have any thoughts or are there any or-tools function regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RoutingModel::VehicleVar(index)`

Pseudo code in Python (using customer_id as node_id)

```py
# Vehicles list
trucks = [1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10]
vans = [4, 5]
pickups = [2, 8]

# location list with a tuple (location, truck, van pickup)
locations = [
  (1, True, True, True), # C-01
  (2, True, True, False), # C-02
  (3, True, False, False), # C-03
  (4, True, True, True), # C-04
  ...
  ] 

for location, truck_allowed, van_allowed, pickup_allowed in locations:
  index = manager.NodeToIndex(location)
  allowed_vehicles = [] # you can add -1 iff the location can be dropped
  if truck_allowed:
    allowed_vehicles.extend(trucks)
  if van_allowed:
    allowed_vehicles.extend(vans)
  if pickup_allowed:
    allowed_vehicles.extend(pickups)
  routing.VehicleVar(index).SetValues(allowed_vehicles)
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L1224-L1226

side note: solver vehicle ID start at 0 but here I followed you vehicle_id convention starting at 1...

Comment: thank you so much! it solved my issue. p.s. if anyone wants to block any vehicle to visit any place ,they can use 'routing.VehicleVar(location_idx).RemoveValues(vehicle_id)'