# VRP with different road_matrix using or-tools

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have same question like [VRP with different vehicle types using or-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835285/vrp-with-different-vehicle-types-using-or-tools/67837375#67837375)

two types of vehicles ：trucks and iveco

according to the traffic control policy of the local ，each types of vehicles can used routes was different :
for example：some road only can be used by trucks , others road only can be used by iveco, some accept both trucks and iveco...
despite this ，using only either trucks or iveco still can traverse all customers finally

now, already get the distance_matrix and time_matrix using only trucks ，and distance_matrix and time_matrix using only iveco

but I couldn't find the right function calculated the best routes , did anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can register a transit function per vehicle type then pass an array of registered transit indices when creating a Dimension.

see this sample on gist: [vrp_multiple_transit.py](https://gist.github.com/Mizux/6d9283388150020df7542adf63577786)